# yq add array element with name and subfields

Tags: yaml, yq

I got this `test.yaml`:

```yaml
volumes:
  - name: var-log
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log
  - name: dev-log
    hostPath:
      path: /dev/log
```

and want to achieve the following using Go `yq` - https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/

```yaml
volumes:
  - name: var-log
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log
  - name: dev-log
    hostPath:
      path: /dev/log
  - name: sys
      mountPath: /sys
```

I cannot really get my head around it - with:

`yq eval '.volumes |= (. + {"name":{"name":"sys"}})' test.yaml` I got it almost, but the 3rd field name is missing (it should be `name: sys` but it is just `name:`)

```yaml
volumes:
  - name: var-log
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log
  - name: dev-log
    hostPath:
      path: /dev/log
  - name:
      mountPath: /sys
```

I'm fiddling for some time now, but cannot get it working.

Comment: Is your desired output valid yaml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either make `name` and `mountPath` appear on the same level:

```sh
yq '.volumes += [{"name": "sys", "mountPath": "/sys"}]' test.yaml
```

```yaml
volumes:
  - name: var-log
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log
  - name: dev-log
    hostPath:
      path: /dev/log
  - name: sys
    mountPath: /sys
```

Or you can make them nested, lacking the "jointing" value:

```sh
yq '.volumes += [{"name": {"mountPath": "/sys"}}]' test.yaml
```

```yaml
volumes:
  - name: var-log
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log
  - name: dev-log
    hostPath:
      path: /dev/log
  - name:
      mountPath: /sys
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!